# To restrict the scope of the search: Site or Site Collection

Tags: search, search-results, search-scope

i will have 3 sites for three different departments. I was thinking to locate them in a single site collection. But there is a requirement that in any departments search result only that site must be scoped. So can we restrict the search scope by sites. Or this is not possible? As i know we can only restrict the searc in site collection scope.

According to your answers i will change my architecture of sites.
Thanks.

Comment: Create your own search scopes, have a look at these [stackoverflow post][1], [stackexchange post][2]

[1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287183/limiting-sharepoint-search-engine-to-a-specific-subsite
[2]: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/44522/how-to-limit-search-crawl-only-to-subsite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You should create custom scopes and add conditions on those scopes
>   limiting results to those coming from the specific URLs. When
>   searching each scope, the users will only see results with URLs
>   containing the starting URL you defined. You can also limit the scopes
>   the users see in the scope selector (or hide the selector), you need
>   to replace the search box embedded in the master page (it's a delegate
>   control) with your own search box (same control, just with your own
>   parameters).
>
> Just go to search settings (under SSP) there you will see a section
>   for scopes. create a new scope and add a condition requiring the URL
>   to contain your site URL. compile the scopes and add them to the site
>   collection search box (under site collection settings --> scopes)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287183/limiting-sharepoint-search-engine-to-a-specific-subsite

however if in future they want to use People Picker feature it only scoped for site collection as far as I know.

hope it helped :)