# Hide folder for particular site collection in SharePoint Online

Tags: search, folder, keyword-query-language

I have 2 site collections on my tenant -

- site collection A
- site collection B.

I want to restrict the end users from searching `folders` from `Site collection A` and allow them to search folders from `Site collection B`.

Is it achievable?

If yes then please help me with `Keyword Query` for the same.

Comment: You have to use Security OR change the default result source (though this is not as good as proper security).

Comment: Have you looked at using scopes? Take a look at this other post. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/47074/to-restrict-the-scope-of-the-search-site-or-site-collection